# Resolve an Interface in a multitenant app without specify concrete class with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant application. I must resolve a type with Autofac. I can do it... It has not been really difficult. Here how I have done:

**FIRST SOLUTION**

```
var tenantIdentifier = new TenantIdentificationStrategy();
var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentifier, container);
mtc.ConfigureTenant("1", t => 
{
        t.RegisterType<MultiTenant.ModuleModule1>()
        .As<MultiTenant.IModule>();

        t.RegisterType<MultiTenant.Controllers.Tenant.Tenant1Controller>()
        .As<MultiTenant.Controllers.CommonController>()
        .PropertiesAutowired();
});

mtc.ConfigureTenant("2", t => 
{
        t.RegisterType<MultiTenant.ModuleModule2>()
        .As<MultiTenant.IModule>();

        t.RegisterType<MultiTenant.Controllers.Tenant.Tenant2Controller>()
        .As<MultiTenant.Controllers.CommonController>()
        .PropertiesAutowired();
});
```

Well... It works perfectly... It works as I expect
But I do not like that I have to add the concrete class for registration. This means that I must add a reference in the project... And, for example, if I have 10 different tenant I must add 10 references to my project.
But I don't really like this situation.

**SECOND SOLUTION**

I have tried to solve in this way:

```
mtc.ConfigureTenant("1", t => 
{
    t.RegisterType<MultiTenant.Controllers.Tenant.Tenant1Controller>()
     .As<MultiTenant.Controllers.CommonController>()
     .PropertiesAutowired();
});

mtc.ConfigureTenant("2", t => 
{
    t.RegisterType<MultiTenant.Controllers.Tenant.Tenant2Controller>()
     .As<MultiTenant.Controllers.CommonController>()
     .PropertiesAutowired();
});
```

And in the web config:

```
<autofac>
   <components>
      <component type="MultiTenant.Module1, MultiTenant.Module" service="MultiTenant.IModule, MultiTenant.IModule"></component>
      <component type="MultiTenant.Module2, MultiTenant.Module" service="MultiTenant.IModule, MultiTenant.IModule"></component>
   </components>
</autofac>
```

This solution "works" but I do not have the expected result because Module1 and Module2 are both resolved for both tenant.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tag your assemblies using a custom attribute

```
[assembly: TenantAttribute("tenant1")]
```

Then list all of them and use the `RegisterAssemblyModules` method inside your `ConfigureTenant`.

If your application run under `IIS`, I recommend using `BuildManager` to list your assemblies (see [Why aren’t my assemblies getting scanned after IIS restart?](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html) for explanation).

You can do something like this :

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> referencedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

if (HostingEnvironment.InClientBuildManager)
{
    referencedAssemblies = referencedAssemblies
                                 .Union(BuildManager
                                            .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                                            .Cast<Assembly>())
                                 .Distinct();
}

var groupedAssemblies = referencedAssemblies.Select(ass => new
{
    Assembly = ass,
    TenantAttribute = ass.GetCustomAttribute<TenantAttribute>()
})
.Where(o => o.TenantAttribute != null)
.GroupBy(o => o.TenantAttribute.TenantId, o => o.Assembly);

foreach (var group in groupedAssemblies)
{
    mtc.ConfigureTenant(group.Key, cb =>
    {
        cb.RegisterAssemblyModule(group);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have just one domain for all tenants. So, When I do `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();`, I get all assemblies, both `Module1` and `Module2`

Comment: I cannot resolve `ass.GetCustomAttribute<TenantAttribute>`.. perhaps it is an extension method... where is it defined?

Comment: It's an extension method defined inside `System.Reflection` [`GetCustomAttribute<T>` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138455(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect... but still do not solve totally my problem. If I have two or more assemblies tagged with the same tenant, I obtain this error:
`The tenant with ID '1' has already been configured. It cannot be reconfigured.`

Comment: Thank you... but now I have antoher problem.. Im sorry... What if  an assembly could be tagged with more tenant? I am trying with `[assembly: AssemblyTenant("1", "2")]` or with `[assembly: AssemblyTenant("1, 2")]`.. I think this is last problem

Comment: Use `[assembly: AssemblyTenant("1", "2")]` and this line between `.Where` and `.GroupBy` `.SelectMany(o => o.TenantAttribute.TenantIds.Select(oo => new { Assembly = o.Assembly, TenantId = o }))` should make it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73413/discussion-between-cyril-durand-and-ciccio).